# How do I find the dtype of the content in a list using Python?

Tags: python

My code consists of the following workflow:

```
if my_list contains dict:
  do_this()
elif my_list contains str:
  do_that()
```

`my_list` contains a large number of elements.

`my_list` can contain only `dict` or only `str` dtypes.

What's the most efficient way using which I can find what `dtype` is contained in `my_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS OP SAY HE WANTS WITHOUT INDEXING THEN USE THIS ONE,

```py
if set(map(type,l1)) == {str}:
    do_this()
elif set(map(type,l1))=={dict}:
    do_that()
```

### Explanation (Because OP is familiar with the [`map`](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/map-in-python#:%7E:text=Map%20in%20Python%20is%20a%20function%20that%20works,passed%20as%20arguments%20to%20the%20map%20in%20Python.) function then I explain the next part.)

```py
map(type,l1) # return [<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]

# And then I use set function here.

# if you are familiar with math then you know the set never contains two same elements.

# After using

set(map(type,l1)) # here it's only return {<class 'str'>}

# then I use 
set(map(type,l1)) == {str} # this is because <class 'str'> is equals to str but `<class 'str'>` not equals to str here You need to make a set here.
```

##### This is what I can explain to you, Please forgive me if you don't understand.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @Luke Of course.

Comment: @Luke Are you familiar with the map function or not. Please be quick.

Comment: Yup I am familiar with map

Comment: @Luke Can I explain this in the comment or do I need to edit my post?

Comment: Would be great if you could edit the answer

Comment: @Luke Give me a minute.

Comment: @Luke Noe check.

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% certain that the list contains either `dict` or `str` data types and they are not mixed, you can just check the data type of the first element using [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(my_list[0], dict):
    do_this()
elif isinstance(my_list[0],str):
    do_that()
```

Comment: What if the OP's list is looks like this `[1,'h']`

Comment: @SharimIqbal They said the list contains only integers or only strings.

Comment: This answer would definitly work for me since I have uniform dtypes in the list, but I was hoping for a workaround without indexing

Comment: @Luke what do you mean with a workaround without indexing?

Comment: Without using `my_list[0]`

Comment: I'll accept your answer if there's no better workaround

Comment: @Luke yes, but then what is your goal? What is it that you want to check? To get the datatype of the items in a list there has to be a check of the datatypes either through indexing or looping perhaps.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, I was trying to see if a workaround like `if check_inside_instance(my_list, dict):` exists

Comment: Ok interesting, I don't know of any built-in function like that. Maybe someone else does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244841/discussion-between-ethan-van-den-bleeken-and-luke).